# Is data sending via ajax to php manipulable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, count

To limit the characters in a textarea a user can type, i put a counter on it.

```
// this is part of tinymce 
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
    var maxchars = <?php echo $max_chars_allowed; ?>; // determined in settings
    var countchars = CountCharacters();
    var charsleft = maxchars - countchars;
```

and the function CountCharacters():

```
// counting characters textarea
function CountCharacters() {
    var body = tinymce.activeEditor.getBody();
    var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
    return content.length;
};
```

Now i send the data via ajax to the php file:

```
// count chars input
var countchars = CountCharacters();
$.ajax({
        url: 'comment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { countchars:countchars }
        ...
```

To check the data in comment.php:

```
$countchars = $_POST['countchars']; // countchars read from ajax 
$max_chars_allowed = 200;
if( $countchars > $max_chars_allowed ) {
    echo 'Max allowed characters exceeded. Reduce characters and submit again';
    ......
```

This all works fine but my main questions is: is it safe to do it this way?
Maybe someone can manipulate the js var **countchars** via the browser inspector and set it, per example, to 100 while literally he typed 300 characters in the textarea? Then after submit, ajax send 100 chars to the php file instead of the 300 he typed in the textarea and the security loop in php will be bypassed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send that count to the PHP code. You're right that that's trivial to bypass. Instead, get the comment text in PHP, and then check its length, and reject it if it's more than 200 characters long.

Your JavaScript code is there just to provide UI. The actual check should be on the actual data, server-side.

---

In a comment you've said:

> Well, i used to check the input it in php with `strlen` but the problem was: js `length` gave me everytime another value then php `strlen`. So when the user gets a message like **2 characters left**, he submits the data and php rejected it because `strlen` in php was 5 characters more then the js `length`

There could be various reasons for that, here are a couple of possibilities:

1. Differences in line endings. Some platforms use `\r\n` (two chars) others use `\n` (one char) (the old Mac OS used `\r`, but that was years ago). You might normalize those when counting:

   ```js
   var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
   content = content.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "\n");
   return content.length;
   ```

   (And then the same sort of thing on the PHP side.)
2. PHP strings are [one byte per character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), but that's not the reality in the world today. (I don't know whether you're using the [`intl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) or [`mbstring`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extensions, but you may want to look into them if not.) In contrast, JavaScript's strings are UTF-16 (but they tolerate isolated surrogates that should normally be in pairs), so for example that means that a lot of characters that count as one character in JavaScript count as more than one in PHP. The `mbstring` extension's [`mb_strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function or similar might help. (Some "characters" even require two or more characters in JavaScript, either because they're represented using surrogate pairs and/or because they use combining marks that are each separate code points in Unicode.)

Comment: If you see a "TL;DR" at the top of the answer, please hit refresh. I misread the PHP code initially.

Comment: Well, i used to check the input it in php with `strlen` but the problem was: js `length` gave me everytime another value then php `strlen`. So when the user gets a message like **2 characters left**, he submits the data and php rejected it because `strlen` in php was 5 characters more then the js `length`

Comment: @john - I've added to the answer to try to help with that.